# Representation of $n$-th derivative as the sum

Tags: derivatives, summation, binomial-coefficients, stirling-numbers

Not so long time working with derivatives I have noticed, that if $f(x)=a^{b^x}$, so for $n\geq0$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=(\log b) f(x) \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} {n \brace k} (\log f(x))^k$$
and also if $g(x)=a^{\frac{1}{x}}$, so for $n>0$
$$g^{(n)}(x)=(-\frac{1}{x})^n g(x) \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!} \binom{n-1}{k-1}(\log g(x))^k$$
How can we prove it? Is there a general method for finding representation of $n$-th derivative as the sum?

Comment: Relevant Wikipedia articles, respectively: [(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials), [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lah_number), [(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: @metamorphy, thank you for comment! Last link is new to me.

Comment: I don't have time to carry this out but you could try log differentiation